# Do I need a work queue for a proccess? BluePrism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have to develop a Robot which has to work for 7 days. I've created the proccess and my question, do I have to create a Work Queue and configure my Proccess or how do I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work queue creation is not a compulsory task, it all depend on process to process until and unless we do not require any output from the BOT and not a large volume of data i.e.

1. We do not need to get status(error/completed) of an item.
2. Business do not need the status report
3. We do not need to keep track of the items got completed and pending

But, I would suggest you to create and use a `Work queue` as

1. It will keep track of number of records got processed
2. Easy to generate business report (how many requests got executed successfully or got exception)
3. For each record item it will give us the status whether it is been executed successfully or got exception
4. We can easily track the error.
5. And the most important : If suppose BOT execution is getting failed due to some reason and we need to restart the BOT then, 
   **A**. BOT will not pick the executed item if we are using `work queue`. It will pick the next pending item from work queue
   **B**. If we are not using work queue, BOT will/can pick the items which were executed previously. There is no point to pick the items which were already got processed.

You can also refer the documentation provided by `Blue Prism` on their portal:
[Work Queue Guide](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/documents/Work%20Queues%20Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You explained it very good now I understand the principle